# Do we have almost sure equality in linear regression?

Tags: regression, probability, linear-model

If we have a linear regression model given by: $Y =\beta_0 + \beta_1X + \epsilon$.
Is this equality in the almost sure sense or only in distribution? I couldn't find anything on this question on the relevant wikipedia pages nor on any other website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is mathematical, with no exceptions, so it is even a stronger statement than either "almost surely" or "in distribution." Just define $E(Y|X=x) = f(x)$  and let $\epsilon  = Y - f(X)$, implying $Y = f(X) + \epsilon$.

In the unlikely case that $f(x) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x$, you get your equation.

Comment: I had one follow up question. So can you "decompose" any random variable say $Y$ in the form $Y= X + \epsilon$ with $\epsilon = Y - X$? But in this case we define $\epsilon$ to be the difference between the two, often it assumed that $\epsilon$ is normally distributed and independent of $X$.